# How to draw a dynamic arrow in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I tried using `pg.draw.arrow()`, but apparently that doesn't exist. I want to create an arrow where the end updates based on the rotation of the line so that they're always aligned. Is this possible?

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650646/rotation-based-on-end-points out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using this function, somewhat based on something I saw on stackoverflow a while ago:

```
def arrow(screen, lcolor, tricolor, start, end, trirad, thickness=2):
    pg.draw.line(screen, lcolor, start, end, thickness)
    rotation = (math.atan2(start[1] - end[1], end[0] - start[0])) + math.pi/2
    pg.draw.polygon(screen, tricolor, ((end[0] + trirad * math.sin(rotation),
                                        end[1] + trirad * math.cos(rotation)),
                                       (end[0] + trirad * math.sin(rotation - 120*rad),
                                        end[1] + trirad * math.cos(rotation - 120*rad)),
                                       (end[0] + trirad * math.sin(rotation + 120*rad),
                                        end[1] + trirad * math.cos(rotation + 120*rad))))
```

I defined `rad` as pi/180 to convert from degrees to radians

If you want to assign it to `draw`:

```
setattr(pg.draw, 'arrow', arrow)
```